# Altenatives for QNetworkConfigurationManager

Tags: c++, qt

I try to use QNetworkConfigurationManager to list all discovered SSID's by operating system, but but it only finds the ones the device has been connected to in the past. What class from Qt can be use or what third-party cross-platform can replace this class?

Comment: What's your os? Did you run NetworkConfigurationManager::updateConfigurations()?

Comment: I run NetworkConfigurationManager::updateConfigurations(), and application is test it in different operating system like several Linux distros and Android.